GetIt singleton registered yet it's erroring
this is my main.dart file, not sure why I'm getting this error
import 'package:bolt2/ui/screens/home_screen/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:bolt2/common_libs.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget with GetItMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: router,
    );
  }
}

final GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;

void main() {
  registerSingletons();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

void registerSingletons() {
  GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton<AppMapController>(() => AppMapController());
  // GetIt.I.registerLazySingleton<LocationController>(() => LocationController());
}

// Access registered controllers
AppMapController get appMapController => GetIt.I.get<AppMapController>();
// LocationController get locationController => GetIt.I.get<LocationController>();


The following assertion was thrown building FlutterMapWidget(dirty):
Object/factory with  type AppMapController is not registered inside GetIt.
(Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
Did you forget to register it?)
'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart':
Failed assertion: line 315 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null'

FlutterMapWidget is a widget that just directly references appMapController, I can provide the code for it
I thought that the registerSingletons function takes care of registering it
